# Perforce repository monitor for Windows

Tags: perforce

I used to work with Subversion and a system tray tool ([SVN Notifier](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/)) to monitor the repository so I would immediately see when my local copy was not up-to-date anymore, and I  am wondering if some equivalent was available for Perforce (on Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Perforce GUI client, you can setup email notifications for as many folders as you like by going to:

1. Connection > Edit Current User... > Reviews tab
2. Right click each of the locations you're interested in tracking and click "Include Tree"
3. Click OK

This assumes the review daemon has already been setup on the server.

See http://public.perforce.com/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_track_changes_to_a_project_I_am_interested_in.3F

Answer (score 3):

stimms answer will certainly do exactly as you ask.

But if you want to go a little further an alternative would be to use the P4 Review mechanism, where you can get Perforce to send you an email if changes are made to a user specified part of the depot. It will need setting up on the server, but is trivial to do. See the Perforce documentation and website and look for "review daemon".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen such a thing but it would be pretty trivial to write.  Just check to see if the output of p4 sync -n contains any informaiton.

Comment: You don't want to do p4 sync -n.  What you want is a review daemon.  That way users can specify in the review field of their user what they are interested in.